# Can RStudio (IDE NOT server) be configured to use remote R setup?

Tags: r, debian, rstudio, docker

I am transitioning my debian setup into one where all debian-repository external apps run in dedicated docker containers.

In this context rstudio, of which I am a heavy user, has me puzzled ... does anybody have insight into whether it's possible to run it as a client to remote R installation?

Comment: Can you explain why you want the answer for IDE not server?  One possibility on Debian would be to tunnel X11 through ssh ...

Comment: Because I want to manage the article installation in my base system, but run the non-debian IDE in an isolated docker container ... I could run the server in the container instead, but am looking for a way to avoid having all of R in the container ... The X11 forwarding you propose has the same issue ... Would then be better of to run the server.

Comment: Would be very useful for all sort of grid-engine systems, where running a web-server on a cluster node isn't always possible.

Answer (score 0):

What is a very cool feature of RStudio is RStudio Server. You install RStudio Server on you Ubuntu server and log in to a specific port where RStudio Server is running. You then get your full RStudio interface in your web browser. This allows you to run all your R analyses from any computer that has a modern browser and an internet connection.

R then runs on the remote server, asking almost no resource from the computer you are connecting from.

Comment: But I'm trying to construct a setup where R itself is not located on the system that runs rstudio - IDE or server.